# MySQL: Order By time is not correct with 12 AM and 1 AM

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

The problem I am facing is that MySQL is considering

> 2015-02-12 01:08:40

smaller than

> 2015-02-12 12:54:49

My Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(time) FROM `dcn_payments` ORDER BY `time` ASC
```

My Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
  `payId` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receipt` char(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `pack` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` char(19) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `opId` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `cId` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `lnId` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`payId`),
  KEY `cId` (`cId`),
  KEY `opId` (`opId`),
  CONSTRAINT `cId` FOREIGN KEY (`cId`) REFERENCES `customers` (`cId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `x1` FOREIGN KEY (`opId`) REFERENCES `operators` (`opId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

My Output

```
time Ascending 1
2015-02-12 01:02:05
2015-02-12 01:08:27
2015-02-12 01:08:40
2015-02-12 12:54:49
2015-02-12 12:55:43
2015-02-12 12:56:33
2015-02-12 12:57:02
```

**EDIT**
I am inserting date('Y-m-d h:i:s') to my DB Column, Am I doing it wrong?
Because I just ended up inserting 12:54 (hh:mm) instead of (00:54) on localhost where my system time is according to 12 hours (if it matters)

Comment: 2015-02-12 12:54:49 is not midnight time, 2015-02-12 00:54:49 is midnight. So the ordering is correct.

Comment: 2015-02-12 01:08:40 is smaller than 2015-02-12 12:54:49.

Comment: Since there's no AM or PM in your times, they should be 24-hour time. So the hours run from 0 to 23.

Comment: I am inserting date('Y-m-d h:i:s') of PHP to the column and it is inserting '12:54' instead of '00:54'

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: @Strawberry I am using DISTINCT to reduce result else there are a lot of entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be inserting `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead of `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')`. The capital H is 24-hour hours, the lowercase h is 12-hour hours. MySQL uses the 24-hour format.

Answer (score 3):

`12:54:49` is approximately five minutes to one, **PM**. `01:08:40` is about ten past one **AM**. One o'clock AM would be represented as `13:00:00`, so MySQL is ordering correctly here.

Comment: I am inserting date('Y-m-d h:i:s') to my DB Column, Am I doing it wrong? Because I just ended up inserting 12:54 (hh:mm) instead of (00:54) on localhost wher my system time is according to 12 hours (if it matters)